# Bootstrap Scrollspy Unable to Detect Navigation

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm building a campaign site for my school. I am implementing a sidebar that changes colour on different sections of the website when its in viewport. I'm unable to make the scrollspy work.

This is what I have: https://codepen.io/aahlfeeyann/pen/oeBGdq

```
<body data-spy="scroll" data-target="#sidebar">
  <div class="wrapper">
    <nav id="sidebar">
      <ul class="sidebar visible">
        <li id="step1" class="active">
          <a href="#hero">
            <span>Home</span>
          </a>
        </li>
        <li id="step2">
          <a href="#about">
            <span>About this Campaign</span>
          </a>
        </li>
        <li id="step3">
          <a href="#mvps">
            <span>Our Participants</span>
          </a>
        </li>
        <li id="step4">
          <a href="#appreciation">
            <span>How to fight Procrastination</span>
          </a>
        </li>
        <li id="step5">
          <a href="#details">
            <span>Event Details</span>
          </a>
        </li>
        <li id="step6">
          <a href="#team">
            <span>Our Team!</span>
          </a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
    <div class="bg-wrapper">
      <div class="section" id="hero">
      </div>
      <div class="section" id="about">
        <h1>About the Campaign</h1>
      </div>
      <div class="section" id="mvps">
        <h1>Our Participants</h1>
      </div>
      <div class="section" id="appreciation">
        <h1>Appreciation...?</h1>
      </div>
      <div class="section" id="details">
        <h1>Event Information</h1>
      </div>
      <div class="section" id="team">
        <h1>About the Team</h1>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

</body>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add `nav` class to `ul` element.
As per Bootstrap Docs

> Scrollspy currently requires the use of a Bootstrap nav component for
>   proper highlighting of active links.

HTML

```
<ul class="sidebar visible nav">
.....
...
..
.
</ul>
```

[Scrollspy Docs Reference](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#scrollspy)

Hope This Helps..

Comment: Hi this worked! Very careless of me to not notice I did not a nav. Thanks!

Comment: @aahlfeeyann, Cool... Happy Coding ... :D